# Translate "Don't follow in fear, lead with light" into Latin

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, translation-check

A late friend of mine came up with the phrase, "Don't follow in fear, lead with light" not long before he passed. I'd like to express this in Latin. He intended the meaning to be all-encompassing and not specific.

Here is my rough attempt:

> Ne in timore sequitur, sed cum bonitate ducit

I didn't choose *lux* for light because I believe he meant leading with goodness, hope, and truth. I also opted to avoid an imperative mood.

Comment: Aren't these imperatives? You have used the third-person. If this is counsel for others then should it be second, or second-person plural?

Comment: Yes, but I recall (and correct me if I'm wrong) that negative imperatives weren't common or something along those lines. I decided to avoid that and go third person so it's more one, "one should not follow in fear, but lead with light."

Comment: @Adam, what about the imperative future? You can keep the third person

Comment: That would be fine with me - I'm really open to different forms of this.